# Devise allow access to protected url with link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, password-protection

I am developing an application which requires users to be logged in - but also want to allow them to share particular information with others - provided they have the correct link.

I am using devise, and check that the current_user has 'purchased' the object they are viewing.

It has come up in conversations that they would like this to be emailed to another person to view this information - but would not like them to have access to their account.

Ie.

```
unless current_user
  redirect_to "/" and return 
end
```

I imagine it will be a simple auth token in the url that I can check and allow them access if it is correct?

```
unless current_user or invalid_auth
  redirect_to "/" and return 
end
```

What is the best way to generate and store this auth token and what is the best implementation method

Cheers

Comment: does the other person HAVE to be a another user, or should it work with anyone?

Comment: No, they are not a user, but have been emailed this 'link'

Comment: Then I'm interested in an answer as well. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393557/ruby-on-rails-private-link-sharing-google-docs-style) is another question which gives an idea of what you can do.

Comment: Is there any risk concerned with people sharing this link further? (paid content, confidential content?)

Comment: Not really, it is used when a user purchases content, and they want to pass it on to their subordinate - would be little value to anyone else. And it would be in their best interests to keep it to themselves.

Comment: Any ideas from anyone?